# Prevent uppercase

Tags: jquery, html

I want to to prevent the user from entering uppercase text in a form input!! I tried removing the last char if it is uppercase, but the char appears before being removed.

Is there a way to stop the text from getting into the input in the first place?

Here is my code so far:

```
$('#s').keyup(function (){
    var lastChar = $('#s').val().substr($('#s').val().length - 1);
    if(lastChar.match('[A-Z]'))
    {
        $('#s').val($('#s').val().slice(0,-1));
    }
});
```

Any ideas ?? Thx !!

Comment: Seems like a bad approach to remove characters if they're uppercase (no feedback on why that would be happening, for example), why not just rewrite them as lowercase...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try keypress or keydown instead of keyup :)

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/YEKzA/

Comment: Really? That's odd... Normally keyup allows you to put the key in, and then fires after you lift your finger off the key. Keypress is the moment you tap it (I have a few validators that use keypress to disable digits from being entered). `lastChar.match(/[A-Z]/g)` doesn't work along with keypress?

Comment: The problem is that the keyup allow to do something after that the char is there already .. !!! can you plz give me an exemple of those filters

Comment: Update: http://jsfiddle.net/YEKzA/ working copy there to disable capitalisations, without blocking other keys as well.

Comment: Thx A Lot Brother !! Sorry 4 My Bad English :D

Comment: That fiddle works for me, but it's seriously nasty in terms of performance and internationalization, what if the letter isn't in A-Z ? Sorry Benno!

Comment: can you put that fiddle in the main answer - at the moment the accepted answer is wrong...

Comment: Done. @Russ, in this case the author wanted A-Z, but you are right. The solution provided by Loktar is probably better in this circumstance because it does less harm to the user and would be faster.

Comment: @RussC, What does 'uppercase' even mean in some languages? I agree whitelising is likely to work better than blacklisting, but it really depends what the domain is...

Comment: Well exactly Toby; the main reason for my comment was to add some Nota Bene to any future users who might use this answer and then wonder why it's not working in Extended character sets. As a display hack, this is sufficient, but as a general practise this is a very bad approach; if you need to filter by case, then do it properly. i18n is fairly big nowadays :)

Comment: To add a further comment to the above, you can use this fiddle and it will accept this string 'äößÕÔoo' but not 'äößÕÔOO'. This is because all of those international capitals appear outside of the A-Z range.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
$('#s').keypress(function(e) { 
   var entered = e.keyCode;
   if(entered < 65 || entered > 90) return false;
});
```

Comment: thx what I really needed to know is that "return false;" prevent passing to keyup !! so no char in text input

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='search']").keypress(function(e) { 
    if (e.originalEvent.getModifierState('CapsLock')) { 
        return false; 
    } 
});
```